# Reactive Programming

Tags: pi-3, gpio

The examples I see for the GPIO input are based on a loop which waits and check if the GPIO is receiving any info. Is there a way of just detecting when a button was pressed without using a loop under the hood? I mean, something like, call this function immediatelly after receiving an input at the GPIO.

Comment: Hello, the search term you are looking for is [interrupts](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=raspberry+pi+gpio+interrupts)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's exactly what interrupts do. In python there is a function `RPi.GPIO.add_event_detect( GPIO_NUMBER, GPIO.RISING, callback=yourCallback)`. You then need to define a function `yourCallback()` where you manage whatever has to happen when the respective gpio senses a RISING edge. A websearch for "raspberry pi gpio interrupt" will reveal several detailed tutorials about that topic.

You still should mind debouncing the button.

Comment: I vaguely remember that Rpi.GPIO is very newbie considerate and debounces by hardware or software (I forgot which) without newbies even knowing what is the meaning of button bouncing.  I remember this well because once I thought I was clever and tried to do debouncing by both hardware and software, but found I wasted time, because Rpi.GPIO always debounces by default.  However I am only 80% sure that I remember things correctly.